# Testcafe not able to communicate with local zat server (zendesk-app-tools)

Tags: testing, automated-tests, testcafe, zendesk-app, zendesk-sdk

I'm building a test suite for our Zendesk apps and testcafe works perfectly fine for our environments but isn't working with a local zat server. When a developer wants to test a change they'll build and run the app within a zat server which talks with the Zendesk instance specified and when ?zat=true is appended to the URL it then loads the local app changes. Testcafe doesn't appear to work with this as the changes don't load and I see no communication with the zat server. We need use a zat server as part of pull requests to test changes before they're merged with other environments. I know this is a rather specific issue but any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: This looks like a bug. However it's hard to investigate it without a reproducible example. Would you mind [submitting](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md) a bug report and adding as much information as possible to the template?

Comment: Sure thing! I'll include as much pertinent information as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was previously using Zendesk app tools (zat) which is now deprecated. The [zcli](https://github.com/zendesk/zcli) interface works with testcafe and is the currently supported implementation for Zendesk apps.